# How to store various time from a stopwatch and use them for calculation in c#?

Tags: c#

```
        if (!responseDetected)
        {
            responseDetected = true;
            bufferedTonePlay.Stop();
            responseStopWatch.Stop(); // to get the response time 
            TimeTakenOutput.Text = responseStopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString() + ":" +    responseStopWatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString() +"seconds";
            MessageBox.Show("" + TimeTakenOutput.Text); // display the various response time.
```

//how to continue from here? is it possible to save all this various response time into an array so that i can use them for calculation.

Comment: Is this asp.net, wpf, winforms, wp?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save all the entries in a `List<TimeSpan>`, and then add a new item when your `responseStopWatch.Stop()` is hit.

```
responseStopWatch.Stop()
elapsedTimes.Add(TimeSpan.FromTicks(responseStopWatch.Elapsed.Ticks));
```

When you start the timer again, you need to make sure that it is reset. You can either do a

```
responseStopWatch.Reset();
responseStopWatch.Start();
```

Or you can use

```
responseStopWatch.Restart(); // Stops time interval measurement, resets the elapsed time to zero, and starts measuring elapsed time.
```

The `Stopwatch` serves the time in different ways. The easiest way is to handle the *ticks* (even when storing to database) and then using `TimeSpan.FromTicks()` when creating a new `TimeSpan`.

**A simple sample:**

```
List<TimeSpan> elapsedTimes = new List<TimeSpan>();

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
Stopwatch sw2 = new Stopwatch();

sw.Start();
Thread.Sleep(2000); // just to get some time on our stopwatch
sw.Stop();

sw2.Start();
Thread.Sleep(1500); // just to get some time on our stopwatch
sw2.Stop();


// add timespans
TimeSpan span1 = TimeSpan.FromTicks(sw.Elapsed.Ticks);
elapsedTimes.Add(span1);

TimeSpan span2 = TimeSpan.FromTicks(sw2.Elapsed.Ticks);
elapsedTimes.Add(span2);

double seconds = elapsedTimes.Sum(x => x.TotalSeconds);
```

Then you can do different calculations on the list as you wish. This example contains a quick sum of seconds from each item in the list.

**EDIT:**

You have supplied very little code in your question, but I'll try to answer your comment.

You would need to have an instance of the `List<TimeSpan>` which lives throughout the test. When the section (sound) starts, you start the stopwatch. You can then have two reasons to stop the stopwatch. Either user triggered, or timeout triggered. Stop the stopwatch, and log the result with the stop reason. You should couple the timespans with a test id.

Comment: we want to track the person response time, using only one stopwatch. Is it possible to use one stop watch only?

Comment: Yes it is. You need to reset your stopwatch after adding the entry to the list and then start it again where you start the measurement.

Comment: This codes are basically for a  hearing test so the person would have to respond quite a few times.Therefore, we would like to add all these various response time together or do some individual calculation to each response time so that we are able to see if the test is reliable. Thanks :)

Comment: @PLSHELP: I have updated the answer, check the edit at the bottom.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot shall try first then :)

Comment: But how do you add up all the values that are already saved into the list?

Comment: You can use Linq. `elapsedTimes.Sum(x => x.TotalSeconds);` to sum the seconds for all entries.

Comment: Am i able to view all the various response times that are in the list so as to make comparisons?

Comment: View all of the time individually like calling a value from an array @scheien

Comment: @PLSHELP: Sure you can. But that would be out of context of your question. Update your question, or make a new one where you explain your problem.